# All commands and ssh connection stopped working after hplip installation

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I am trying to configure a print server on an Ubuntu Server 16.04

After the installation of HPLIP package all the commands I try to execute on the command line stopped working.

I have rebooted the system and it didn't work. I checked my .bashrc and .profile files and they are OK.

Now, as my commands on the command line are not working I cannot undo the installation or try anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. It looks like the server is your home router, why don't you go and take a look inside directly?

Comment: I will try to do that

Comment: Crossposted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556629/all-commands-and-ssh-connection-stopped-working-after-hplip-installation

Comment: Unfortunately, even accessing the system directly, nothing was working. The solution was to make a backup of everything and reinstall the system completely.